# Python + psycopg: type '23' for column when in fact 'double precision' in postgresql database

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I use psycopg2 in python to access a postgresql database.

I first collect rows with a fetchall:

```
rows=cur.fetchall()
```

Then, for each row, I modify the type from postgresql format to python format:

```
for row in rows:
    rec={}
    for k in range(len(row)):
        print k
        rec[columns[k]]=PGData2PY(row[k],str(types[k]))
    rtn.append(rec)

def PGData2PY(d,t):
    """
    translate pgdb data to python data 
    params: d: data; t: data description
    return python data
    """
    if t == 'text':
        return str(d)
    elif...
    else:
        print t
    return d
```

I have just received a type t = 23, when in fact it is supposed to be a "double precision" column in my postgresql database. The particular value corresponds here to an integer in the database.

How come it does print t = 23 and not t = 'double precision' or anything similar?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here: psycopg2 converts types from PostgreSQL to Python for you. No need to do your own conversion.

Comment: I was using pgdb until recently, and it looked to me I had to do it myself...

Comment: What would be the equivalent code in psycopg2?

Comment: Just use the data. The type is alredy right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there was not need to create PGData2PY function. A simple

```
for row in rows:
    rec={}
    for k in range(len(row)):
        print k
        rec[columns[k]]=row[k]
    rtn.append(rec)
```

works.